# ML Messages not connecting automatically to some accounts

Tags: macos, messages

I love the new Messages app in Mountain Lion, but there seems to be an issue while using it with a Yahoo account. My Yahoo account does not reconnect after the machine goes into standby or after a restart, I always have to manually connect that account, while other accounts work fine.

Does anyone know of a way of getting the Yahoo account to automatically reconnect? An AppleScript that tells Messages to connect the Yahoo account would be great too.

Edit: this seems to happen with my Gmail account as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a sort of solution to this bug. What I did is write an AppleScript which tells Messages to connect all accounts when one of the accounts successfully connects. I use Messages with Gmail, Yahoo and Bonjour, so when either of those connects, it "tells" all other accounts to connect. It's not failure-proof, but it seems to keep my accounts online properly so far.

```
using terms from application "Messages"
    on login finished for theService
        log in service "Yahoo!"
        log in service "Gmail"
        log in service "Bonjour"
    end login finished
end using terms from
```

Usage instructions:

1. Edit the AppleScript above to include the services you are using
2. Save it using "AppleScript Editor.app" to a .scpt file
3. Open Messages > Preferences > Alerts
4. Set the script to run for the "When I Log In" event.

N.B.

For the line containing `log in service "<service>"` you will need to replace `<service>` with the value you find in the Description field for that particular service in Messages’ account preferences. In my case my Yahoo! account had ”Yahoo” in its description field so I had to change `log in service "Yahoo!"` to `log in service "Yahoo"`. Ditto for the other services.

Comment: In El Capitan, there is only a script handler now. How does one go about caching the 'When I Log In' event?